# Type 'Observable<Observable<Employee[]>>' is not assignable to type 'Observable<string[]>'

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm trying to filter a mat-autocomplete form this way:

***ngOnInit* function:**

```js
filterEmployee() {
    this.filteredOptions = this.employee.valueChanges.pipe(
      startWith(""),
      map((value) => this._filter(value))
    );
  }
```

**Filter function**

```js
private _filter(value: string): Observable<Employee[]> {
    const filterValue = value && value.toLowerCase();
    return of(
      this.employees.filter(
        (employee) =>
          employee.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(filterValue) > 1
      )
    );
  }
```

And there's this error:

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You try to return Observable of array of strings but you have write Observable of employees.
You can update Observable<string[]> like this :

```
private _filter(value: string): Observable<string[]> {
    const filterValue = value && value.toLowerCase();
    return of(
      this.employees.filter(
        (employee) =>
          employee.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(filterValue) > 1
      )
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

first of all, don't `map()` to an `Observable` (I mean, you could, but that's not what you want here).
I think you've confused `map` with `flatMap`.

```
private _filter(value: string): Employee[] {
  const filterValue = value && value.toLowerCase();
    return employees.filter(
      (employee) =>
        employee.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(filterValue) > 1
    );
}
```

Now you'll assign `Observable<Employee[]>` instead of `Observable<Observable<Employee[]>>`

Can we see the definition for `this.employees` and `Employee`?

Comment: ```this.employees``` is the return of the API with the object Employee

```this.employeeService.read().subscribe((response) => {
      this.employees = response["data"];
      this.filterEmployee();
    });```

Comment: @Ari OK, so `employees: Emplyee[]`? And What's the definition of `Employee`? If it's not a string, and `filteredOptions` is a `string[]`, you can't just `filteredOptions = employees.filter(...)`;. You need to `employees.filter(...).map(employee => employee.someFieldThatIsAString)`. It's hard to help without a full example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example, that's why you got downvoted